# Non toxic staining and finishing solutions

Tags: discussion

At this point in my woodworking I am not comfortable nor do I have the proper setup to do this safely (*That and my wife said no*). Fumes and working temperature are my hurdles.

Would 2 separate questions about making my own stains and finishes be too broad. At least for stains there are many different ways but they are mostly rooted with the same ideas.

Comment: There's no way to know without a bit more detail about the proposed questions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what problems you are asking about specifically, it's a bit difficult to know if your question is "too broad."

In general, consider if your question is specific enough that it can be reasonably be *completely* answered in this format. A question like "How do I make stain?" is more the subject of a book than anything that can be reasonably answered in this format… so that's too broad. But if you're actually somewhat knowledgeable in this area and get stuck on a specific problem, that sounds like a "right sized" question for this site.

Whether you're actually asking one question or two is a different matter. If you're reasonably certain that your two use cases are rooted in the same "problem", I would simply say so and ask it as ***one*** question. If it turns out you are wrong, it is simple enough to ask a new question in another thread.